# How to encrypt the Mass(many) files with PGP Public Key using Kleopatra or another tool?

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, pgp, openpgp

I'm trying to encrypt the file to share with vendor to load into their system after decrypting the Files (with their private Key).

I'm using the Kleopatra to encrypt the files which is supporting one file at a time. but I need to encrypt 500 files.

Anyone have idea How to encrypt the Mass(many) files with PGP Public Key using Kleopatra or any other tool/method, please do share?

Thanks,
Jag